# Power Query: How do I make a custom column for rows that have duplicate values in 2/3 columns?

Tags: excel, powerquery

So I have 3 columns.

```
Column A is the subject
Column B is receipt date
And column C is the order result
```

The order result is only listed in one row per duplicate subject. I want to make a custom column in power query that prints yes for both subjects if one of the subject rows has an order result of “T”

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns4", "T issued?", each if List.Contains(Table.SelectRows(Table.SelectRows(each [SUBJECT_ID] = [SUBJECT_ID] and [RECEIVED] = [RECEIVED]),
each [ORDER_RESULT] = "T"
)[ORDER_RESULT],
"T"
)
then "Yes"
else null)
```

I’m getting an error message that says:

```
“Expression.error: 1 arguments were passed to a function which expects 2.

Pattern=
Arguments=[List]”
```

I’m very new to PQ syntax so I’m not sure how to properly write the formula or address my error.

Comment: Did any of these answers help at all? If so, please upvote that answer and then accept it as solution

Answer (score 0):

Matching receipt date and subject, returns yes if any (or each) of order results is T

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns4","T issued?",(x)=>if List.Contains(Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns4", each x[subject]=[subject] and [receipt date]=x[receipt date])[order result],"T") then "yes" else null,type text),
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Alternate #1: ignore case so we pick up T or t:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns4","T issued?",(x)=>if List.Contains(Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns4", each x[subject]=[subject] and [receipt date]=x[receipt date])[order result],"t",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "yes" else null,type text),
```

Alternate #2: T only on a single row, if more then 1 row has T not valid

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns4","T issued?",(x)=>
    let a=Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns4", each x[subject]=[subject] and [receipt date]=x[receipt date])[order result]
    in if List.Contains( a,"T") and List.Count(List.RemoveNulls(a))=1 then "yes" else null,type text),
```

Comment: So I used the alternate #1 formula. It added a custom column and now all the rows read as “table”. Should I be expanding the table?

Comment: the sample input I show produces the sample output I show using alternative#1 Your code must not be matching my example -- , using wrong column names, including the word each, or something else. Examine your raw code in home...advanced editor... and compare

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.AddColumn(
PRIOR_STEP, 
"Custom", 
each if 
Table.IsEmpty(
    Table.SelectRows(
        #"Changed Type", 
        (x) => x[subject] = [subject] 
        and x[receipt date] = [receipt date] 
        and x[order result]="T"
    )
) then "" else "yes"
```

)

Main thing here is you have two functions that need functions as arguments.  Table.AddColumn's 3rd argument is a function and Table.SelectRow's 2nd argument is a function as well.

You can only use the each function ONCE.  Each is syntax sugar for a nameless function.  It lets us write formulas in a more concise way.  Instead of writing **(_) => _[Column Name]** you can write **each [Column Name]** instead.  When you have two function arguments, you cannot use each twice because the underscore (_) has already been defined.  You have to use a different variable like (x) => so that x now represents the elements of Table.SelectRows for instance.

In the formula above the underscore or no prefix at all (_[subject] or [subject]) represents the current row's information in the table.

x[subject] represents the subject of each record in the table that we defined in Table.SelectRows.

Comment: What does “PRIOR_STEP” indicate? It said it was recognized so I deleted it from the formula and now it’s returning errors since it’s expecting 3-4 arguments. Sorry I’m just really not familiar with adding custom columns in power query

Comment: PRIOR_STEP mean in that place, place the name of whatever the name was for the prior step when examining your code in home ... advanced editor.... like #"Renamed Columns" or    #"Added Custom" or whatever

Comment: The prior step is the the line right before the current one... e.g.
let
 step1 = stuff,
 step2 = something(step1,something else),
 current_step = some_other_formula(step2, ... blah blah)
in
 current_step

step2 is the prior step before current_step